# Memoir: Correcting page-numbers using openleft

Tags: header-footer, memoir, page-numbering

I'm writing a book, where I want chapters to begin on the left page (due to the language which is written from right to left...).

However, using `memoir` with `openleft` and `twoside` gives me the problem that the chapter `asd` (see example below) begins on page `ii`, and not page `i` as desired:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openleft]{memoir}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{blindtext}    

\begin{document}

\copypagestyle{foo}{headings}
\makeevenhead{foo}{\thepage}{}{\rightmark}
\makeoddhead{foo}{\leftmark}{}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{foo}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}    

\frontmatter

\chapter{asd}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

I have tried resetting the pagenumber-counter using `\setcounter{page}{0}`, but to no avail. What is the proper way to reset the counter?

Comment: Regarding your other post [Memoir: Preparing document to be read from right to left (Persian script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497423/43317), your question seems to be a [XY Problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/43317). Maybe you should load package `xepersian` and remove option `openleft`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your real document will have something before your `\chapter{asd}` but for your MWE if you put

```
\mbox{} % empty text
\setcounter{page}{-1}
```

between `\frontmatter` and `\chapter{asd}` then put

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

between `\chapter{asd}` and `\Blindtext` I think that you will get what you asked for: A blank recto page, a verso page numbered i with the ASD chapter and then pages numbered from ii onwards.

I don't like it. --- GOM