# Memoir: Preparing document to be read from right to left (Persian script)

Tags: xetex, pdftex, memoir, page-numbering, xepersian

I'm writing a book in Persian, so it is read from right to left. That means that all odd pages should have a wide right-margin, whereas even pages should have a wide left-margin. All chapters should also start on odd pages.

Here is a MWE of my current document:

```
\documentclass[14pt, extrafontsizes, openleft]{memoir}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

This produces a document where the margin is correctly widest in the right part of the page where the chapter starts. However, the chapter starts on page 2, and not 1 as it should?

Why is this? And what is the correct way to configure my preamble such that it understands that I am writing a document that is to be read from right to left?

---

See this picture for visual:

[image]

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=32626&sid=2507ab35a5d030fb0b78adb2fbd1de85)

Comment: Remove option `openleft`, then chapters start on odd pages.