# Memoir: Switch left-right margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, margins, memoir, pagestyle

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

This produces the following document:

[image]

Now the widest margin is on the right for odd pages and left for even pages. Is there a way to reverse/switch the left-right margins, so the widest margin is on the **right** for even pages and **left** on odd pages?

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=32629&p=109709#p109709); [relatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497423/memoir-preparing-document-to-be-read-from-right-to-left-persian-script)

Comment: Based on Ijon Tichys answer to your [crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=32629&p=109709#p109709): loading package `xepersian` the issue can not be reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is. Read chapter 2 in the documentation (`> texdoc memoir`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlrmargins{2in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

where `\setlrmargins{<spine>}{<edge>}{<ratio>}` sets the spine margin, the outer margin, or one of these and the ration between them. The above will give a spine margin of 2 inches and an outer margin of 1 inch.

Books, which I assume you are trying to write as that is what the `memoir` default of `twoside` is aimed at, normally have the edge margin twice that of the spine margin so that when the book is opened the three "margins" (outers and across the spine) are equal. I suggest you think carefully about what you want --- print a few pages double-sided, put them together, and see how they look.

Comment: In the code above \setlrmargins{2in}{1in}{*} should be changed by \setlrmarginsandblock{2in}{1in}{*} in order to run correctly.